Obtain TypedDict from SQLAlchemy declarative class
I have a few ORM class definitions representing tables in my database.
import datetime
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

# ORM class
class Predictions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'predictions'
    uid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    event_date: Mapped[datetime.date]
    location: Mapped[Optional[str]]

# ... other tables

The problem is I would like equivalent TypedDict type definitions for each table, since I will be returning queried rows as dicts:
# desired TypedDict
class PredictionsDict(TypedDict):
    uid: str
    event_date: datetime.date
    location: Optional[str]

How can I automatically generate type definitions (that will be picked up by intellisense) for TypedDicts without manually keeping multiple classes in sync? I am using SQLAlchemy 2 and Python 3.9.

You would need a plug-in for whatever is consuming your source, or use a tool to inject derived definitions directly into the source.

You can't add something like PredictionsDict = Predictions.make_typed_dict() to your source, because that would a dynamic, not a static, property of your code.

@chepner that makes sense when you put it that way. Definitely more of a headache than it's worth. Thanks!
